# How to map or make struct for variable json response in golang?

Tags: json, api, go, struct

I am calling an API and getting json and don't know how to make a struct for the response I have used JSON-to-GO to get a struct for the response. But the problem is the response is not same every time.
For example I have a struct using the JSON-to-GO :-

```
type Autogenerated struct {
    Response struct {
        Results struct {
            Status      string `json:"status"`
            StatusCode  int    `json:"status_code"`
            ResultsData struct {
                ResultsCount       int `json:"results_count"`
                NearbyCount int `json:"nearby_count"`
            } `json:"results_data"`
            SortData struct {
                SortBy string `json:"sort_by"`
            } `json:"sort_data"`
            ResponseData struct {
                Data0 struct {
                    Name string `json:"name"`
                } `json:"data_0"`
                Data1 struct {
                    Name string `json:"name"`
                } `json:"data_1"`
            } `json:"response_data"`
            Time float64 `json:"time"`
        } `json:"results"`
    } `json:"response"`
}
```

The Data1 and Data0 can be any more like **Data2, Data3....** and I want the **Name** inside of the Data0, Data1 ....
I am very new to golang, Maybe we can use Map for it but due to being not same all the time I don't know, how to do it.  Also there are a lot of filed along with **Name** which I have not pasted here to keep the question clean.

Comment: Use a map for that part.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I can keep the struct same upto ResponseData and inside of that I can use Map? A little illustration would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes, You should replace `ResponseData struct { ... }` with `ResponseData map[string]interface{}`, for example.

Comment: Or possibly `map[string]struct { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `map[string]interface{}` for Response data type. Data0 to any number os Data0 type fields unmarshal to map as keys `data_0, data_1, data_2`

```
ResponseData map[string]interface{} `json:"response_data"`
```

If your Data coming as a same object for every data_0 ... data_n, then define struct type like below and define map with that type.

```
//new data type
type Data struct {
    Name string  `json:"name"`
}

//add this to your Autogenerated struct 
ResponseData map[string]Data `json:"response_data"`
```

or simply add

```
ResponseData map[string]struct{
    Name string `json:"name"`
} `json:"response_data"`
```